# Rearranging the alphabet (VB)

Tags: vb.net, key, alphabet

I wanted to basically rearrange the alphabet with a keyword infront as I am doing a simple substitutional cipher. I have kind of worked out the logic of doing that but I am a bit stuck on the coding side.

What I wanted was something like:

```
Dim key = "keyword"

    For i = 0 to 26

    'insert keyword and put in A to Z after without duplicating characters

    Next


'output: keywordabcfghijlmnpqstuvxz
```

Comment: Could you give us more of the 'rules' to follow? From what we have so far, you don't need a (for) loop ... Just append `abcfghijlmnpqstuvxz` in front of your `key` value.. If this is not the full approach you have in mind, please let us know more

Comment: @NonymIty: He does not want to repeat the characters of the keyword in the appendix.

Comment: yeh the for loop was to check for unique characters. I am still very new to this language :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think looping through the key is cleaner than looping through the alphabet:

```
Dim key as string = "keyword"

Dim alphabet As new StringBuilder("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

for each c As Char in key
    alphabet.Replace(c.ToString(), Nothing)
next

return key & alphabet.ToString()
```

or slightly more efficient change the replace line as follows to avoid scanning all 26 letters of the alphabet on each iteration:

```
    alphabet.Replace(c.ToString(), Nothing, 0, 1)
```

Comment: This solution gets more effective as the key get longer: key.len x ((26+key.len)/2) times. (The alphabet get shorter as it get's removed). The other solutions: 26 x key.len times.

Comment: @GerhardPowell I agree this one searches less, but isn't this one key.len X alphabet.len / 2 (aka key.len X 26 / 2 aka key.len X 13) not counting a shrinking alphabet.  It only gets better (faster) on each pass.  Can you elaborate on the `+key.len` you mentioned?

Comment: Sorry. Mistake in my formula. key.len x ((26 + (26-key.len))/2). So the avg of the alphabet and alphabet with all the keys removed.

Comment: @GerhardPowell Go it, very nice.  If you use my 2nd Replace command then that number is divided in half yet again because the alphabet scan jumps out after finding a match.  So on average an alphabet scan will need only to visit 1/2 the characters.  So after much reducing that is key.len x (52 - key.len) / 4.  Like you said, it should get more efficient the longer the key.

Answer (score 3):

```
Public Function Rearrange(keyword As String) As String
    Dim cipher As New StringBuilder(26)
    cipher.Append(keyword)
    For c As Char = "a"C To "z"C
        If Not keyword.Contains(c) Then
            cipher.Append(c)
        End If
    Next
    Return cipher.ToString()
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution in vb:

```
Public Function words(key As String) As String
    Dim ret As String
    ret = key
    key = key.ToLower()
    For c As Char = "a"c To "z"c
        If Not key.Contains(c) Then
            ret = ret + c.ToString
        End If
    Next

    Return ret
End Function
```

If you want to check for unique char for the key, then you can just run a for loop through the characters of the key and remove the current char if already exist. Remember to move the for loop one char back if you delete the char.

Comment: Thanks :) I will try remove the character if they are duplicated